# How to backup Synology DS Note Station

Tags: synology

I am running the Note Station plugin on my Synology box but I do not where the files are being stored for Note Station. I tried looking for a private folder in my user's home directory but no luck. I would like to make sure the Note Station database is backed up incase I need to restore. Anyone know where it's at? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notes are saved on your NAS using Sqlite3 which is stored here:

/volume1/@appstore/NoteStation/db

Note that you can also use the Backup & Replication utility in DSM 5.1 to backup your Notes.

Comment: ... or Hyper Backup in DSM 6.0

Comment: so does selecting up the "NoteStation" under "Apps" in Hyper Backup include a backup of the actual notes or does this only backup the app itself and the settings?

Comment: I looked at the sizes of the three files I have in that folder, then create a note containing a 300kb file and synced, then checked the files sizes again. They were identical. The note is definitely on the server but it must be stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a backup solution for NoteStation. I found this tutorial which provides a good overview of setting up the NAS for use with Amazon Glacier Service.

http://wahlnetwork.com/2014/10/27/synology-to-glacier/

The only downside is you can't currently backup application data (which I don't think you really want to do with the Glacier service anyways). To solve this I'm using the S3 service which is configured in the AWS site similarly as described in the link above, but instead uses the Synology Backup & Replication tool. The main idea is Glacier backs up the data that is recovered infrequently (like photos in the case of a disaster) while the S3 backs up data that might be accessed more frequently (like NoteStation which is used daily and in which you may want to revert changes).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.